# EDAC reports error on a csrow that does not exist

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

The kernel log shows many instances of the following EDAC error:

`EDAC MC0: 1 CE ie31200 CE on unknown memory (csrow:3 channel:1 page:0x0 offset:0x0 grain:1 syndrome:0x1c)`

The thing is... there is no `csrow #3` on my system (output truncated for visibility):

```
$ ls -l /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 May 19 10:53 csrow0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 May 19 10:53 csrow1
```

How can that be? Is there *actually* a faulty memory device? How can I identify which it is?

More information that may help:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/ce_count
1069

$ cat /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/csrow?/ce_count
0
0

$ sudo edac-util -v
mc0: 0 Uncorrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: 0 Corrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: csrow0: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: mc#0csrow#0channel#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: mc#0csrow#0channel#1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: mc#0csrow#1channel#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: mc#0csrow#1channel#1: 0 Corrected Errors
edac-util: No errors to report.
```

- OS: ArchLinux / 5.17.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT
- CPU: Xeon E-2124
- Motherboard: SuperMicro X11SCH-LN4F

Thank you

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour on an HPE ML30 Gen10 with the same CPU. The rate of reports seems to correlate with temperature in the chipset/pcie area